# Tar progress per file with pv for multiple files/folders at a time?

Tags: bash, tar, bash-scripting

I've been using this one line command that I found on another post here and it works great for one folder at a time. This is the command:

```
tar -cf - /opt/folder1 | pv -s $(du -sb /opt/folder1 | awk '{print $1}') | gzip > archive.tar.gz
```

How can that be changed to work for multiple files/folders at a time and get the overall progress, rather than running the same command for each folder/file. Here is the use case:

I have /opt/folder1, /opt/folder2 and /opt/folder3/*.db files. These can all be combined like into one variable like this.

```
filestobackup=(
        /opt/folder1
        /opt/folder2 
        /opt/folder3/*.db
    )
```

This does not work:

```
tar -cf - "${filestobackup[@]}" | pv -s $(du -sb "${filestobackup[@]}" | awk '{print $1}') | gzip > archive.tar.gz
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Quick answer**: change the line into

```
tar -cf - "${filestobackup[@]}" | pv -s $(du -cb "${filestobackup[@]}" | tail -1 | awk '{print $1}') | gzip > archive.tar.gz
```

**Long answer**: The problem is that `du` will produce several output lines and not just one as in the single directory case. Switch `-s` makes `du` print the total size for **each** entry. Since you are passing several entries to `du` (two for folder1 and folder2, plus one for each `.db` file in folder 3), `du` will print something like:

```
2112345 opt/folder1
57148   opt/folder2
388     opt/folder3/foo.db
161     opt/folder3/bar.db
```

By using switch `-c`, `du` prints one last line containing the grand total. In order to use this value, you have to filter `du` output to get only the last line.

This can be done either with awk, that you already use in the pipe, or, more simply, although with a (minor) performance penalty, by adding a `tail -1` filter.